# html half screen video background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a video as a banner on my page, but I also want the users to see the posts and other stuff. The lacity.org is a great example, tried to do the same but I can't set the height once I set the width to 100%

```css
.video-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

#video {
  object-fit: cover !important;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <video class="video" id="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" preload="auto">
<source src="https://www.lacity.org/sites/g/files/wph1221/f/EchoPark_1920x800_loop.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Böngészője nem támogatja a  a HTML5 videót</video>
</div>
```

Tried to set the height with px and vh but these are not responsive. If I set the height to 50%, nothing happens. The example: https://www.lacity.org/

Comment: if you use px the video-container will change.

Comment: if you want to make it smaller you can definetly just set the height with px or something, that works fine, if you didnt see changes you probably missed to refresh your browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will add padding to the container like this:

the percentage set depends on the video dimension.

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.video-container {
  padding: 20.85% 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#video {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <video class="video" id="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" preload="auto">
<source src="https://www.lacity.org/sites/g/files/wph1221/f/EchoPark_1920x800_loop.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Böngészője nem támogatja a  a HTML5 videót</video>
</div>

<p>Other content go here.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only problem that it's not half-screen large. You can't see the posts because the video is too large.

Comment: won't this change the width of the video tho without the object-fit? so when you set height lower than 100% it also looses width

Answer (score 1):

In your styling, you have to do this:

```
#video {
  object-fit: cover !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px; /* You can change the height to whatever you want here. */
}
```

And that's it. You just have to change the height to px.
It (the height) has to be in px or vh.

Comment: _“When you specify the width in %, then you can't specify the height in %.”_ - that is simply not true. The actual restriction when it comes to setting height in percent, is that the parent element must have a defined height as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try with set padding top:

https://usefulangle.com/post/142/css-video-aspect-ratio

```css
.video-container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    height: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

#video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <video class="video" id="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" preload="auto">
<source src="https://www.lacity.org/sites/g/files/wph1221/f/EchoPark_1920x800_loop.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Böngészője nem támogatja a  a HTML5 videót</video>
</div>
```

Comment: If I set padding-top, there will be an empty space above the video.